# OperationalError: not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, formatting, pygresql

I'm running the following code:

```
#converts strings that are ints to int.
for i,x in enumerate(values):
    try:
        values[i] = int(x)
    except:
        pass

# Fills values with NULLs if needed
if len(values) < no_of_columns:
    values = values + ["NULL"]*(no_of_columns-len(values))
print(values)

# Creates dict with params and values
params = {}
for i, x in enumerate(values):
    params[i] = x

query = "INSERT INTO {} VALUES ({});".format(table_name,",".join(['%s']*no_of_columns))

self.cur.execute(query, params)
self.print_answer()
```

And what happens is I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "interface.py", line 228, in <module>
    db.run()
  File "interface.py", line 219, in run
    actions[self.print_menu()-1]()
  File "interface.py", line 194, in insert
    self.cur.execute(query, params)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pgdb.py", line 323, in execute
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pgdb.py", line 359, in executemany
pg.OperationalError: internal error in 'BEGIN': not enough arguments for format string
```

This confuses me because when I print params and quote I can see that there are exactly as many elements as there are `%s` tags:

```
params = {0: 22, 1: 'ehj', 2: 'NULL', 3: 'NULL'}
query = 'INSERT INTO books VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s);'
```

What am I doing wrong? The parameters should be the same amount as the %s's, right?

Comment: I suspect you need to pass in the `values` list, not a dictionary. Does `self.cur.execute(query, values)` work?

Comment: Yes, it does, thanks a lot!

Comment: I would suggest that the first value 0 : 22 isn't  a string and you therefore need to use %d  to format it.
Edit: Sorry, my mistake. '%s'%22 works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

- You are using *positional* parameters, each `%s` would match a successive value in the second argument to `cursor.execute()`, which should be a *list or tuple* here. You want to use `values` and not build the `params` dictionary at all.
- You should not use the string `NULL` for nulls, use `None`; strings will be inserted literally (so not a SQL `NULL`, but the *string value `'NULL'`), the Python value `None` represents actual nulls.

  Alternatively, you could replace parameters with `NULL` values in the generated `INSERT` statement (so the generated SQL has `NULL` literals rather than parameters.

I'd also not use blanket `except:` statements; you are silencing any and all errors. Just catch `ValueError`:

```
#converts strings that are ints to int.
for i,x in enumerate(values):
    try:
        values[i] = int(x)
    except ValueError:
        pass

# Fills values with NULLs if needed
values += [None] * (no_of_columns - len(values))
    
query = "INSERT INTO {} VALUES ({});".format(
    table_name, ",".join(['%s'] * no_of_columns))

self.cur.execute(query, values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't escape string, if you just pass the exception, you will alter the passed values order. Also the database will do the conversation, so no need to `int()` anyway.

```
#converts strings that are ints to int.
for i,x in enumerate(values):
    try:
        values[i] = int(x)
    except:
        values[i] = x # see note above
```

also, here is my solution to the same problem:

```
def db_insert(conn, cur, table, data):
    sql = ('INSERT INTO %s (' % table) + ', '.join(data.keys()) + ') VALUES(' + ', '.join(['?' for j in data.values()]) +')'

    cur.execute(sql, tuple(data.values()))
    lastid = cur.lastrowid
    conn.commit()

    return lastid
```

you can use it like this:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_PATH)
cur = conn.cursor()

db_insert(conn, cur, 'ig_media', {
   'user_id': uid,
   'media_id': mid,
   'like_date': arrow.now().timestamp
})
```